# matlab print -depsc error

Tags: matlab, printing, eps

I have a really frustrating problem with Matlab. I want to convert a Matlab plot into an eps file. It has always worked fine, last time about half an hour ago, but now it seems to not work anymore. Whenever I type in the command:

```
print -depsc filename.eps
```

Matlab says:

```
Error using validateHandleToPrint (line 26)
No Figure to print.

Error in validate (line 17)
pj = validateHandleToPrint(pj);

Error in print (line 201)
    pj = validate( pj );
```

Comment: Aren't you leaving off the figure handle? So like `H = plot(x,y); print H -depsc filename.eps` ?

Comment: Have you tried to restart MATLAB?

Comment: Are you sure you still have the figure? Is it visible? Are you working in terminal environment on in full MATLAB IDE?

Answer (score 0):

If you call the function [`print()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/print.html) without explicitly passing a graphic handle, it will try to print the [`gcf()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/gcf.html), the current figure handle.

If, for some reason, the current graphic handle is not valid anymore (e.g. you closed the figure), then it will throw the error you got.

You can print conditionally by checking with [`ishghandle()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/ishghandle.html):

```
if ishghandle(gcf)
    print ...
end
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. It seems that I've never closed the figure before when I called the print command.

Comment: Is there a way of printing it into eps format without having the figure open at the same time?

Comment: You can set the figure to invisible with `set(gcf,'Visible','off')`, plot in the figure, then print it and `delete(gcf)` before going to the next one.